# How to do unit testing on a repository with putfile in the function

Tags: php, laravel, file, unit-testing, phpunit

How to do unit testing on a repository with this in the function:

```
\Storage::putFile($path, $file);
```

When I test this I get:

> 1) Tests\Unit\SellPageTest::testSellPageRepoStore Error: Call to a
>   member function hashName() on integer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use this to pass the issue and to get the name =>

UploadedFile::fake()->image('file.png', 600, 600)